# Why does this array copying not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning javascript and I am trying to copy the contents of one array to another using the following code:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [];

// I expect it to copy elements from arr1 to arr2
arr1.forEach(Array.prototype.push, arr2);

// I expected the length of arr2 to be 3
console.log(arr2.length);  // but it logs 9
```

Kindly don't suggest me alternatives ways to copy array contents, I am learning JS and want to know why does it not work? Thank you

Comment: Just look at the value of arr2 after you execute the code. It will be unexpected :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect `arr2`, you'll see that it contains this:

```
Array [ 1, 0, Array[3], 2, 1, Array[3], 3, 2, Array[3] ]
```

This is because `forEach` [yields **three** arguments to supplied callback: element of the array, index of that element and the array itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). All those are added by your handler to `arr2`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing `Array.prototype.push` as the function, it will take all the three parameters (item, index, array ) which `forEach` callback handler takes and pushes it to the array.

look at this output

```
[1, 0, Array[3], 2, 1, Array[3], 3, 2, Array[3]]
```

You are adding item at `n+0th` index, index at `n+1th` index and array at `n+2th` index.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in a function to strip out the second and third argument that `forEach` passes to the `push`:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [];

arr1.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
  this.push(value);
}, arr2);

console.log(arr2);
```